# printing a python code multiple times (NO LOOPS0

Tags: python, string, printing

I've been having trouble getting a specific print in Python 3.4
Input:

```
str=input("Input Here!!!:")
num = len(str)
x = num
print (((str))*x)
```

but I'm looking for an output that prints str x times, without using a loop.

for example if I enter:

```
Input Here!!!: Hello
```

I would get:

```
>>>Hello
>>>Hello
>>>Hello
>>>Hello
>>>Hello
```

Comment: don't use keywords for variable names.

Comment: What is the problem? Looks like you've done it.

Comment: You want to get Hello in separate lines, the output you have given is the expected output? Please include more information.

Comment: @AvinashRaj: I know what you mean, but you *can't* use keywords for variable names, so that's not really a problem..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a newline if you want the output on different lines:

```
In [10]: n = 5

In [11]: s = "hello"

In [12]: print((s+"\n")* n)
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

It is not possible to get the output as if each string were the output of a new command. The closest to your expected output will be the code above.

Comment: There is an extra newline at the end. Try using `rstrip` to remove it.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi unless he added that by self, which doesn't look the case.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi, yes  `((s+"\n")* n).rstrip()` will remove if that is an issue

Answer (score 0):

You should never use built-in keywords, types for variable names. `str` is a built in type like list, int etc.  Next time you would try to use it, will give you errors.

Ex -

```
>>> str = 'apple'
```

Now let's try to build a simple list of no.s as string.

```
>>> [ str(i) for i in range(4)]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#298>", line 1, in <module>
    [ str(i) for i in range(4)]
```

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Since we have already replaced our str with a string. It can't be called.

So let's use 's' instead of 'str'

```
s=input("Input Here!!!:")
print ( s * len(s) )
```

If you want output in different lines

```
print ( (s+"\n")* len(s) )
```

Comment: It was more of an attempt to clean his answer and mention no use of reserved.

Comment: But `str` is used to convert some input to string, like int etc. Maybe technically they are called something else. I don't think it's good to use it.

Comment: hmm my bad, but still one should not use function names as variable names, right?

Comment: Can you three discuss this in chat please?

Comment: My bad. Yes, you are right. It is a built-in type which is overloaded to accept calls.

Comment: back to same, so one should use built in types, list, int, str as variable names? Definitely next time you would call it there would be an error. Like next time he tries to convert to some string.

Comment: thx @PadraicCunningham, Malik would change it to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` with a list comprehension:

```
>>> s='string'
>>> print('\n'.join([s for i in range(5)]))
string
string
string
string
string
```

Technically a list comprehension is a 'loop' I suppose, but you have not made clear what you mean by 'without using a loop'

You can also use string formatting in Python:

```
>>> fmt='{0}\n'*5
>>> fmt
'{0}\n{0}\n{0}\n{0}\n{0}\n'
>>> print(fmt.format('hello'))
hello
hello
hello
hello
hello
```

But that will have an extra `\n` at the end (as will anything using `*n`)

---

As Tim points out in comments:

```
>>> print('\n'.join([s]*5))
string
string
string
string
string
```

Is probably the best of all...

Comment: How about `'\n'.join([s]*5)`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly do you want to achieve. We can always **`replicate looping`** with a **`recursive function`**.

```
def input(s):
    print(s)

def pseudo_for(n, my_func, *args):
    if n==0:
        return
    else:
        '''
        Write function or expression to be repeated
        '''
        my_func(*args)
        pseudo_for(n-1, my_func, *args)

pseudo_for(5, input, "Hello")
```